# how to have a shared layout for specific routes in nextjs

Tags: next.js, signalr

how to have a shared layout for specific routes in nextjs? I want to create a singleton object(signalR connection object) in one place within a common layout for some related routes(chat routes) which have common businesses and use this object in all these routes, please help me with this

Comment: Quick search on google gives you some references: https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/
Next.js is not really architectured for having a shared layout (yet), common stuff should most often happen in `_app`

Comment: Have you considered a CSS grid solution.